# nginx - rewrite trailing slash optimisation

Tags: docker, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure a `docker compose` setup using an nginx proxy to route requests to seperate containers. It's working as expected but I'm having some difficulty with multiple slashes occurring.

If the user lands on `example.com/handle` all is fine and the resulting path is `/`

If the user lands on `example.com/handle/` all isn't fine as the resulting path is `//`

Currently I've got the below

```
location /handle {
    rewrite ^/handle(.*|$) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass          http://container:8000;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and ofcourse I figure it out as soon as I post a question. This works as expected

```
location /handle {
    rewrite ^/handle/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass          http://container:8000/;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```